# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

unable to find the error in the loop...please help me

```
foreach($cat1 as $category){
    $query="SELECT parent FROM categories where id=".$category;
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    array_push($cat1,$line['parent']);
    }
```

Comment: Try checking for errors, it sounds like somethings not successful - such as not connected to db, wrong table name or wrong column name..

Comment: Which type of data store in $category

Comment: Is this _all_ you have in your loop? Reading the error again, `$resource` is a _string_. Usually this will report it as a boolean for a failed query. Somewhere you are overwriting `$result`

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to either an empty result set or an error in your query.

Please use following steps to debug:

- `echo $query` first (check if all parameters are there)
- `Write mysql_query($query)` or `die(mysql_error());`

This will show you mysql errors if any.

Answer (score 0):

Before fetch, you shuld check `$result` **to be sure you works with resource**. Also, check if you really have a rows from query with `mysql_num_rows`.

```
foreach($cat1 as $category){
    $query="SELECT parent FROM categories where id=".$category;
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // Check result
    // This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        array_push($cat1,$line['parent']);
    }
    else {
       // do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also try debugging the query, by running:

```
SELECT parent FROM categories where id=3
```

or insert a valid value ID after `id=`

Also, is the field being selected: `parent` a INT or VARCHAR? (my guess is, it's a string, based on your error provided)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_fetch_assoc($result) == 1) {

    $score ++;
}
```

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\answer\get_answer.php on line 24

Comment: format the code, in code box, this doesn't considered as a good way of writing  answer